# Can simple logic conditions be created from nested complex conditions

Tags: logic

I have complex conditions like `((x>10 and y<10) or x>1) or z<5 and y>5` can all these be broken down to simple conditions with just and/or by removing nesting? Is there any name for the method which does so.

I am thinking yes they can be formed. I intended to form them as, For each of 5 conditions above evaluate the expression for all possible outcomes(true/false). combine using "Or" the conditions where it is true.

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you mean, but try looking up [disjunctive normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form)

Comment: Thank you for your response. if I have some condition with parenthesis.  Can I expand it in all cases to a condition having simple "and" "or"?

Comment: It seems I want a "normal form". I still not sure what is the name of the normal form which does not have parenthesis, I am looking at this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tpdDlsg4Cws Thank you.

Comment: Yes I want a disjunctive normal form. Is there any algorithm to do that. To do that using a truth table seems complex and proportional to 2^(simpleconditions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want "does not have parentheses" and you're using the usual precedences for the connectives ($\neg$ binds tighter than $\land$ which binds tighter than $\lor$), then what you need is the [disjunctive normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form).

Every Boolean expression has a DNF representation, but its size may be exponential relative to the original expression, so $O(2^n)$ in the worst case cannot be avoided.

In practice you can often get through quicker than building a full truth table -- just keep rewriting the formula using

1. De Morgan's laws to push negations towards the atomic conditions at the bottom, and
2. The distributive law $P\land(Q\lor R)\equiv P\land Q \lor P \land R$ to float the disjuctions above the conjunctions.

When neither rewriting can be applied any more, the formula is in DNF.